# NULL values populating when trying to calculate a percentage in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, calculation

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' then 1 Else 0 end) Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events,
    COUNT(*) - 'Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events' AS Total_Number_Outage_Events,
    ROUND(('Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events' / 'Total_Number_Outage_Events') * 100) AS Forced_Outage_Percentage,
    YEAR(Start_Time) as Year
FROM AEMR
WHERE Status = 'Approved'
GROUP BY
    Reason,
    YEAR(Start_Time)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(Start_Time),
    Reason
```

***OUTPUT***

| Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events | Total_Number_Outage_Events | Forced_Outage_Percentage | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 181 | NULL | 2016 |
| 1264 | 1264 | NULL | 2016 |
| 0 | 106 | NULL | 2016 |
| 0 | 380 | NULL | 2016 |
| 0 | 127 | NULL | 2017 |
| 1622 | 1622 | NULL | 2017 |
| 0 | 102 | NULL | 2017 |
| 0 | 320 | NULL | 2017 |

Comment: Could you please add some more details like sample data from the table. You can check out some other questions to understand how other users have posted their questions in a easily understanding manner.

Comment: @StanGeo How would I add sample data from the table???? Sorry I am so new to this that I feel so stupid on how to communicate

Comment: please provide sample data , what you get as output right now and whats your desired output

Comment: @MicahCollins You can share table creation statement along with insert statements. And please mention which dbms you are using?

Comment: Should these strings (`'Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events'`, `'Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events'` and `'Total_Number_Outage_Events'`) escaped column names? In mysql you escape them with backticks instead. Since mysql doesn't throw an error in this case, I assume it casts them to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coalesce() to replace NULL values with 0:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' then 1 Else 0 end) Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events,
    COUNT(*) - Coalesce('Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events',0) AS Total_Number_Outage_Events,
    ROUND((Coalesce('Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events',0) / Coalesce('Total_Number_Outage_Events',0)) * 100) AS Forced_Outage_Percentage,YEAR(Start_Time) as Year
FROM AEMR
WHERE Status = 'Approved'
GROUP BY
    Reason,
    YEAR(Start_Time)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(Start_Time), Reason
```

You used column aliases in same select list I don't know which database allow it so I am changing the query:

```
 SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' then 1 Else 0 end) Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events,
        COUNT(*) - SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' then 1 Else 0 end) AS Total_Number_Outage_Events,
        ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' then 1 Else 0 end) / (COUNT(*) - SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' then 1 Else 0 end))) * 100,0) AS Forced_Outage_Percentage,YEAR(Start_Time) as Year
    FROM AEMR
    WHERE Status = 'Approved'
    GROUP BY
        Reason,
        YEAR(Start_Time)
    ORDER BY
        YEAR(Start_Time), Reason
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go now - sorry for the formatting errors I'm still learning how to share and post properly

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: they have us in Next.Tech

Comment: SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events
,Count(*) as Total_Number_Outage_Events
,CAST((CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS DECIMAL(18,2))/CAST(Count(*)
 AS DECIMAL(18,2)))*100 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as Forced_Outage_Percentage
,Year(Start_Time) as Year
FROM
AEMR
WHERE Status = 'Approved'
GROUP BY
Year(Start_Time)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_Number_Forced_Outage_Events
,Count(*) as Total_Number_Outage_Events
,CAST((CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Forced' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS DECIMAL(18,2))/CAST(Count(*)
 AS DECIMAL(18,2)))*100 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as Forced_Outage_Percentage
,Year(Start_Time) as Year
FROM
AEMR
WHERE Status = 'Approved'
GROUP BY
Year(Start_Time)
```